# Which Hadoop Distribution should i choose among cloudera, MapR and Hortonworks?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I just started working on a new project where i need to setup/Implement Big data Hadoop environment. I want to know in this current technology world among the hadoop distribution enterprises which one should i choose- Cloudera or Hortonworks or MapR or AMZN based on both technical or cost perspective ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I have experience working with all 4. And they all have their advantages/disadvantages.

MapR has clearly cheaper TCO and technologically superior platform, Cloudera is a bit more polished, Hortonworks for pure open source (don't read this as free or cheap, as most companies end up spending more money on HW to get any value).

Would be good to understand your use cases before we can comment further on what fits best for your use case.

Comment: I appreciate your response. We are going to analyze health related data from various sources like insurance companies, Hospitals, clinics etc..Also would you please share your idea about Data Center base Vs Cloud Base?

Comment: our use case would be as i told earlier healthcare related data, where datasize may very 10TB to 30TB per month.We may have to process both batch and real-time. For data visualization and dashboard type report presentation Tableau  might be used. These are the very primary scenario right now I have. Also would you please share your idea about cloud base Vs DataCenter approach? Which should be better way to proceed on?Any guidance or links towards any useful information would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: From distribution point of view, it doesnt really matter if you are on on-premise or cloud. Send me a pm, can e-mail you some stuff on that.